# How can i insert data from a text file to mysql?

Tags: php, json

I have some data in JSON format in a text file as below. I need to insert this data into mysql using php but can't do it.

```
{"address":"+92 334 6629424","service_center":"Test Sending Sms","id":3,"locked":0,"person":0,"protocol":0,"read":0,"reply_path_present":2,"seen":0,"error_code":0,"status":1,"date":1873326412,"thread_id":1,"type":-1}
```

My PHP file has the code like this.

```
<?php $source_file  = "SMS2012-05-21.txt"; $handle = fopen("SMS2012-05-21.txt", "r");
$col_names = implode(",", fgetcsv($handle)); // Getting comma separated list of col name

 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 mysql_select_db("messages");
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
 $values = "";
 foreach($data as $key => $value) {
     if ($key != 0) $values .= ", ";
     $values .= "'".mysql_escape_string($value)."'";
 }
 mysql_query('INSERT INTO messages ('.$col_names.') VALUES ('.$values.')');
 }
 ?>
```

I can't find any result nor any error. Could any one please help me in this regard that where i am wrong?

Comment: You should use `json_decode` on the text file since its JSON data, not CSV data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [json_decode](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to manipulate json data.

```
<?php


  $source_file  = "SMS2012-05-21.txt";
  $string = file_get_contents($source_file);
  $json = json_decode($string,true);

  //DB Conn Handling Stuff

  $cols = array(); $values = array();

  foreach($json as $key=>$value)
  {
      array_push($cols,'`' . $key . '`');
      if(is_string($value))
      {
         array_push($values,'\''.$value.'\'');
      }
      else
      {
         array_push ($values, $value);
      }
  }

  $col_name = implode(',',$cols);
  $col_value = implode(',',$values);

  $query = 'INSERT INTO messages('.$col_name.') VALUES ('.$col_value.')';
  mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(echo mysql_error());      

?>
```

Comment: I am receiving the following error in response of this code.  Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in D:\wamp\www\admin\admin\jsondecode2.php on line 16,  and this: Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\wamp\www\admin\admin\jsondecode2.php on line 21. Please tell me where it should be corrected.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake on array_push, in the order of the arguments. First the array, then the string to be pushed.

I've edited the post an now it's correct

Comment: it is giving the following error now. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read,reply_path_present,seen,error_code,status,date,thread_id,type) VALUES (92 3' at line 1

Comment: strange... i've not tested database insertion, but, the echo of the query seemed correct to me...

Please do this and post the results here:

`echo $query;`

Comment: maybe it's a quotation problem

i've edited the function, please replace and post feedback

Comment: echo $query gives following: INSERT INTO messages('address','service_center','id','locked','person','protocol','read','reply_path_present','seen','error_code','status','date','thread_id','type') VALUES ('92 334 6629424','Test Sending Sms',3,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,1873326412,1,-1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've missed something, you should use it in this way:

```
<?php $source_file  = "SMS2012-05-21.txt"; 
$handle = fopen("SMS2012-05-21.txt", "r");
$data = fread($handle, filesize($source_file));
$jsonArray = json_decode($data, true);

$keys = implode(',', array_keys($jsonArray));
$values = "'" . implode("','", $jsonArray) . "'";

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db("messages");

mysql_query('INSERT INTO messages ('.$keys.') VALUES ('.$values.')');
```

Comment: i m receiving following error in this code's response: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in D:\wamp\www\admin\admin\jsondecode2.php on line 4, and this: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\wamp\www\admin\admin\jsondecode2.php on line 6 and: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in D:\wamp\www\admin\admin\jsondecode2.php on line 6. Plz tell me ASAP about its solution.

Comment: It has not given any result. I have my messages table created before at same column names as for $keys. but this code is not giving any error nor any result.